# How do I turn off presidential alerts on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, alert

I already have Settings > Notifications (bottom) > AMBER Alerts and Emergency Alerts turned off, yet I still get Presidential Alerts.

How can I turn off Presidential Alerts?

iPhone 5, iOS 10.3.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“The Communications Act of 1934 established the authority for the President to use certain private sector communications systems for priority communications, such as sending alert and warning messages to the public, during national emergencies,” FEMA wrote. “The Warning, Alert, and Response Network (WARN) Act of 2006 prompted the Federal Communications Commission to adopt regulations enabling the wireless industry to participate in the distribution of public alerts and warnings also. **The WARN Act further established that the wireless alerting service should allow wireless subscribers the capability of opting out of receiving WEA alerts, other than an alert issued by the President**.”

Therefore, you are not able to opt out of the Presidential Alert.

Comment: What's next? Presidential Alerts directly into your brain with the iTelepath? It's _my_ device! I _own_ it! I should be able to control what notifications I receive! Guess I'll have to wait for Purism Libre 5 https://puri.sm/shop/librem-5/. Was hoping for a used iPhone X after the new batch of X's came out. So sad.

Comment: You can disable such alerts on Android though! https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253456/is-there-a-way-to-disable-national-alerts-on-rooted-android-devices/253457#253457